# Python / Email processing: How to get the date an attachment was created?

Tags: python, imap, email-attachments, imaplib, imapclient

I have a Python program that will read an Outlook inbox using these Python libraries:

```
1. IMAPClient
2. email
```

I want to know if it is possible to get the date the email attachment was created.

I don't see anything in email headers that stand out.  I can get the date an email was sent (or forwarded), but it is the case when an email is forwarded that prompts this question.

I want to get the date of the attachment inside the email.  If anyone has done this, and has a full working code snippet to share, it would be greatly appreciated.

---

I have done several searches, looked carefully through email headers, looked at the two library documentation I am using (IMAPClient, and email), and see nothing that stands out that would lead to a solution.

Comment: This information is not included in the email.

Comment: thinking about sending an email, a file is attached and then the email is sent. The date of the attachment would not be, practically, the same as the sent date?

Answer (score 0):

Some file formats include this, most don't, some may. For example the EXIF data in some JPEG files includes it. To read that you'll need an EXIF library, not an IMAP library. Microsoft Word files include a creation date, IIRC that's mandatory for that format, but again you'll need a type-specific library.

IMAP is merely the channel through which you download the data you want to examine.